# Async/await for a beginner

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have an app that uses GeoLocator to find the users position.
It looks like this:

```
public async (not sure what to put here) Cordinates()
{
    if (_geolocator == null)
    {
        _geolocator = new Geolocator();
    }

    Geoposition _Position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
}
```

I also have a string property that I would like to use to describe the proces.

```
public string Status {get; set}
```

For example when the `Cordinates()` begin the string-value should be "Searching..." and when the `Cordinates()` is done it could say "Done"

I think this is a situation where I should use await/async but I could use some help getting it right please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set your return type to `Task<T>` if you return something or `Task` if you return nothing (`void`). for example if you have a line like `return _position;` then you should make the return type of your function to `Task<Geoposition>` or if you have `return 0` you should change it to `Task<int>` and if you just dont return anything or simply `return` just use `Task`.

```
public async Task<your return type> or Task if return type is void Cordinates()
{
    if (_geolocator == null)
    {
        _geolocator = new Geolocator();
    }
    this.Status = "Searching..."; // seting status and awaiting your async GetGeoposition
    Geoposition _Position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    this.Status = "Done"; // after GetGeoposition is finidshed you are here and setting status to done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read into the basics of async/await and threading before using it.
A good start is maybe [Stephen's post here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

To fix your code, it will be something like this (see also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) for reference):

```
public async Task<Geoposition> Cordinates()
{
  if (_geolocator == null)
  {
    _geolocator = new Geolocator();
  }

  Geoposition _Position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
}
```

In the `Status` your would check if the current position has already been queried or not. Depending on that, returns a string value of your choice. No async operations in there. Alternatively, set the statue before and after where you await the geoposition.